# Retrieve string values with list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am having some problems trying to manipulate some strings here. I am scraping some data from a website and I am facing 2 challenges:

1. I am scraping unnecessary data as the website I target has redundant class naming. My goal is to isolate this data and delete it so I can keep only the data I am interested in.
2. With the data kept, I need to split the string in order to store some information into specific variables.

So initially I was planning to use a simple `split()` function and store each new string into list and then play with it to keep the parts that I want. Unfortunately, every time I do this, I end up with 3 separate lists that I cannot manipulate/split.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome('\\Users\\rapha\\Desktop\\10Milz\\4. Python\\Python final\\Scrape\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/2020/7851/MS011/match-stats")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser" )

for infos in soup.find_all('h3', class_='section-title'):
    title = infos.get_text()
    title = ' '.join(title.split()) 
    title_list = []
    title_list = title.split(" | ")
    print(title_list)
```

Here is the "raw data" retrieve

```
Player Results
Tournament Results
Salvatore Caruso VS. Brandon Nakashima | Indian Wells 2020
```

And here is what I like to achieve

```
Variable_1 = Salvatore Caruso
Variable_2 = Brandon Nakashima 
Variable 3 = Indian Wells 
Variable 4 = 2020
```

Could you please let me know how to proceed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

Its not so pretty but will work as long as there is always a VS. and a | separating the names and that the date is always 4 digits for the year.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/lewis/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/2020/7851/MS011/match-stats")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser" )

text = soup.find_all('h3', class_='section-title')[2].get_text().replace("\n","")
while text.find("  ")> -1:
    text = text.replace("  "," ")
text = text.strip()
#split by two parameters
split = [st.split("|") for st in text.split("VS.")]
#flatten the nested lists
flat_list = [item for sublist in split for item in sublist]
#extract the date from the end of the last item
flat_list.append(flat_list[-1][-4:])
#remove date fromt the 3rd item
flat_list[2] = flat_list[2][:-4]
#strip any leading or trailing white space
final_list = [x.strip() for x in flat_list]

print(final_list)
```

output

```
['Salvatore Caruso', 'Brandon Nakashima', 'Indian Wells', '2020']
```

Comment: Thank you for that, this is quite helpful & indeed answering to part of the challenge. Having said that, your start with the right string. One of the problem I have is that I cannot remove the 2 others (['Player Results'] ['Tournament Results']), I always end up dealing with the 3 at the same time & cannot use specifically the one you used in your example. How should I proceed here?

Comment: i've updated it :) please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I just checked the update but unfortunately the initial string is still not like the one return by the scrap. You are using a unique string that contains the 3 elements while the scrap returns 3 autonomous string that I can hardly merge or separate actually.

If you use my code and print the type of title variable, you'll see it returns 3 strings, but I cannot target specifically each string to separate them or merge them.

Comment: See, when using your code, I end up with the same problem as when using mine, it returns separated lists inherited from the separated string blocks.

This is what happened after line "flat_list = [item for sublist in split for item in sublist]":
['Player Results', 'ults']
['Tournament Results', 'ults']
['Salvatore Caruso ', ' Brandon Nakashima ', ' Indian Wells 2020', '2020']

and then, targeting index [2] does not work; the only index that works is [0]

Comment: Still the same problem :/ (I also assumed it came from the spaces & the backslash for lines initially, but it does not seem to make a difference)

Comment: Try it again - it works fine for me. Restart your kernel if working with jupyter and see what happens. I've changed one of the variable names as there was a conflict. (copy any paste the code and add in your webdriver)